# Деплой Spring Boot/PostgreSQL проекта через Gradle и Docker

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, spring-boot, docker-compose

Здравствуйте. Возникла проблема с деплоем, над которой я уже бьюсь больше суток. 
Ситуация такая: пишу бэкенд для мобильных приложений на стеке:

1. Spring Boot 1.5 + Dev Tools
2. PostgreSQL
3. Docker
4. Gradle

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
      image: mobilebackend      
      ports:
          - 8088:8080
      depends_on:
          - db
      links:
         - db
    db:
        container_name: transneft_db
        image: postgres
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - transneft_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
            - POSTGRES_USER=user
            - POSTGRES_DB=db
            - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
        ports:
            - 54320:5432
    adminer:
        image: adminer
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8082:8080
volumes:
    transneft_db: {}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:54320/db
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

jwt.secret =aotransneftsibir

logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.10.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath('se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'docker'
apply plugin: 'application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
    mainClassName       = "com.backend.MobilebackendApplication"
}

jar {
    baseName = "backend-api"
    group    = "com.backend"
    version  = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
    manifest { attributes "Main-Class": "com.backend.mobilebackend.MobilebackendApplication" }
}

docker {
    baseImage "frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim"
    maintainer 'Alex Scrobot "scrobot91@gmail.com"'
}

dependencies {
    // spring boot
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')

    //postgresql
    runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')

    //gson
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7'

    // JWT
    compile 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.0'

    //test env
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
}
```

На локалхосте все отлично запускается, когда контейнер с постгресом запущен, все работает, все отлично.

Проблемы начинаются, когда я пытаюсь вызвать

`./gradlew build distDocker --refresh-dependencies`

В этом случае в `spring.datasource.url` должен обязательно стоять localhost, иначе билд образа сфейлится. В итоге, собранный образ из градла я пытаюсь поднять docker-compose'ом, и получаю ошибку соединения с БД. В причинах я разобрался, схема такая:

контейнер с .jar поднимается, пытается постучаться по localhost:db_port, но внутри контейнера он найти его не может, естественно. Поэтому нужно указать вместо localhost:db_port -> db:db_port, где db - это service_name из `docker-compose.yml`
Но, тут начинается самое интересное, при сборке образа, спринг просто не может увидеть `db:db_port`, и билд фейлится.. Что делать - не знаю.. Мне начинает казаться, что я слишком тупой для таких высоких технологий))) Подскажите пожалуйста, может я неправильно все понял, И проблема решается за 1 минуту?

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую вам внутри кластера также поднять виртуальную сеть, например:

```
networks:
  main:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: *.*.0.0/24
          gateway: *.*.0.1
```

где **main** - это имя сети. Теперь для каждого контейнера в кластере можно указать эту сеть в качестве размещения, а также IP-адрес:

```
networks:
  main:
    ipv4_address: 172.30.0.12
```

Подробно работа с сетями на кластере Compose описана в разделе [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks) официальной документации.

P.S.: Не будьте к себе так критичны))

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле, дело было не в бобине)))) 
Разобравшись в вопросе мапинга сетей, мне открылась истина: соединение между контейнерами идет через внутреннюю сеть, маппинг на хост это просто настройка haproxy в составе докера, который будет перенаправлять запросы на хостовую машину в контейнер, а на сеть самого контейнера маппинг не влияет никоим образом. 
Таким образом, приложение должно искать БД на db:5432, а вот БД интерфейс, в моем случае adminer, уже ищет конект на localhost:54320